# Prefix for only some fields in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid which have multiple rows and columns. I have applied a formatter for a column that adds prefix $ as below:

```
{name:'Due_Amount', index:'Due_Amount',  width:50, align:"right", editable:false, formatter:'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 0, prefix: "$ "}},
```

If there are 30 rows in the grid, i want to have this prefix for only 25 rows and the remaining 5 rows should not the prefix as they are not currency fields.

Any idea on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't seems to be sooooooo clear ...!!!

Comment: Consider the example below that is close to my requirement

Jan----------------------$35
feb----------------------$34
March--------------------$25
%Due in quarter 1-------- 46

Here for the fourth row "%Due" i don't want to add prefix $ as it not currency field.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I can understand such requirements. It's very strange to place in one column **mixed** information. If the column is "Amount" then all items should be amount. The requirement about "the remaining 5 rows" sounds very strange. If the user change the order of sorting then the rows can changes its position. Isn't so.

In any way the usage of `formatter: 'currency'` is wrong with such kind of data. You can use [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) to implement your custom requirements.

Comment: It looks like your answer consists of merely the last sentence.  Maybe you can expand that into an actual answer?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: To write more details one need know more exact requirements. On can easy write custom formatter which formats cells in different way based on `id` of the row or based on the of the cells from the row, but one can't do this based on **position** of the row in the grid. The requirement formulate about "the remaining 5 rows" from "30 rows in the grid". I think it's not real requirement and like I described above one can't use *position* of the row inside of custom formatters.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll close the question.